# How to select a property inside of an object dynamically in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am using an api from the public-apis from github and it basically gives information about the country that we request
Now I have encountered a problem and I don't really know how to figure it out
I want to create a card based on the information on the api but I want to do it dynamically and not hardcoding the information inside of the api

This is the structure of the api:
{
other properties,
languages: { eng: "English" },
other properties
}

When I change the country, the eng object inside of the languages object also changes, the example above is for the USA while when I try to get the information for Portugal, I get this:

{
other properties,
languages: { por: "Portugese" },
other properties
}

So the name of the object inside of the languages object changes

How can I select that object inside of languages dynamically? I mean surely I can select them like this:

obj.languages.eng for USA and obj.languages.por for Portugal, but how can I select it dynamically and not hardcoding it myself?

I even searched about getting a property in an object by its index but I found out there is no such thing like index in objects in comparison to arrays

Comment: [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) ... `obj.languages[Object.keys(obj.languages)[0]]`.

Comment: How do you want to select the property? What's the search criteria? How do you know you want `por` and `eng`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an unfortunate choice for that API designer to have made. Object properties should be consistent. `langKey` (`"eng"`, `"por"`) and `langName` (`"English"`, `"Portuguese"`) properties would have been more useful. **If** you can change the API, I'd suggest doing that.

If not:

> ...but how can I select it dynamically and not hardcoding it myself?

If the object **always** has just a single property, you can get the value by using the first (only) element of the iterable returned by [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values):

```
const [value] = Object.values(obj.languages);
```

Examples:

```js
function test(obj) {
    const [value] = Object.values(obj.languages);
    console.log(value);
}

test({ languages: { eng: "English" } });
test({ languages: { por: "Portugese" } });
```

---

In a comment you asked:

> What if we had multiple values inside of that object that we needed to look for?

If there may be multiple properties, you need **some** way to knowing which property/properties have the values you want and which ones don't. Without specifics, I can only point you at the various tools to interrogate an object's properties, such as [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) above, [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames)... But it really depends on what you know about the structure. It's a very unfortunate choice for an API design.

Comment: What if we had multiple values inside of that object that we needed to look for?

Comment: @MehrshadCheshmKhavari Your question then needs to be updated with more clarity and detail to specify that kind of requirement so answers can be better tailored to it.

Comment: @MehrshadCheshmKhavari - If there may be multiple properties, you need **some** way to knowing which property has the value you want. For instance, if you know the names of all the other properties (and they don't change), you could figure it out in a couple of different ways (such as getting an array of all of the property names of an object via `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`, then eliminating the ones that you know about). But it really depends on what you know about the structure. It's a very unfortunate choice for an API design.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I don't know why is it designed like this, thanks anyway